# Bold and underline dropdown list menu item asp.net

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, bold, underline

i got a  questiong to ask. I got a dropdown list in my app.However the dropdown list is populate with hierarchy format.  Please c the picture

[image]

As the picture above. How can i bold and underline the parent menu item such as **Men** , **ladies** and **NA** On the other hand , the parent item is not allow to select also.

Here is my coding

```
        private void createDDLCategory()
    {
        ddlCategory.AppendDataBoundItems = true;
        ddlCategory.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("All","A"));
        ddlCategory.SelectedIndex = 0;



        var ddl1 = dropdownlist.ddlCategoryWithoutGroup();
        foreach (var value in ddl1)
        {
            if (value.P_CATEGORY_ID == null)
            {

                this.ddlCategory.Items.Add(new ListItem(value.CATEGORY_NAME, value.CATEGORY_ID.ToString()));
                this.ddlCategory.Items.FindByValue(value.CATEGORY_ID.ToString()).Selected = false;

                this.ddlCategory.Items.FindByValue(value.CATEGORY_ID.ToString()).Attributes.Add("disabled", "true");
                this.ddlCategory.Items.FindByValue(value.CATEGORY_ID.ToString()).Attributes.Add("style", "font-weight:bold;");

                foreach (var valueChild in ddl1)
                {

                    if (valueChild.P_CATEGORY_ID == value.CATEGORY_ID)
                        this.ddlCategory.Items.Add(new ListItem("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" + valueChild.CATEGORY_NAME, valueChild.CATEGORY_ID.ToString()));
                }
            }
        }


        foreach (ListItem item in ddlCategory.Items)
        {
            item.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(item.Text);

        }



    }
```

Ur help is appreciate.Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried this way:

```
ddlCategory.Items.FindByValue("0").Attributes.Add("style", "font-weight:bolder")
```

MSDN has mentioned that only few style attributes are applicable for IE.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/dnaspp/html/controlscrashcourse-deriving.asp